# CSS `overflow-wrap: break-word;` applied to sequence of whitespaces

Tags: css, word-wrap, line-breaks, trailing-whitespace

I struggle to understand what's the expected behavior of `overflow-wrap: break-word;` when applied to a long sequence of whitespaces, and specifically Ideographic Space (U+3000).

So far I've actually tested on all kind of [whitespaces](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Zs) (Unicode Category “Zs - Space Separator”). In Chrome, all of other whitespaces wrap except Ideographic Space. But in Safari, Ideographic Space also wraps like others. See demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Ideographic Space</title>
    <style>
      .container {
        width: 2ch;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: normal;
        white-space: normal;
        font-family: monospace;
      }

      span.text {
        background-color: rgba(50, 10, 100, 0.15);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <span class="text"
        >&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</span
      >
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <span class="text"
        >&#x3000;&#x3000;&#x3000;&#x3000;&#x3000;</span
      >
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've gone through related [CSS Specs](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-text/#overflow-wrap-property), but fail to understand how to interpret it on this specific point. And since two popular browsers behave differently, I guess this could be a bug in one of them, I'm just not sure which (but intuitively, I guess Chrome is to blame).

I want to make Ideographic Space wrap like other whitespaces in Chrome, but I don't really want to use `white-space: break-spaces`, which does work, but it also comes with other undesired behaviors like preserving unwanted whitespaces.

Here's the [svelte page](https://svelte.dev/repl/d01f7096a4174d7fbed48c56f9938839?version=3.55.1) I used to experiment on the problem.

Hope someone familiar with the subject can shed some light on it. Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth Firefox exposes the same behavior as Chrome here. Looking at WPT tests I can't see that interop issue being tested.

Comment: Yeah I've skimmed through WPT too, but cannot find a test case on this specific one.